# Function in a wordpress shortcode

Tags: shortcode, buddypress

from days i have a problem, sorry for my bad english.

I've wordpress with buddypress + woocommerce + wc vendors pro.

I need show member products list inside his buddypress profile.

This list is called by shortcode:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[wcv_products vendor="USERNAMEHERE"]' );
```

I think to resolve with the user buddypress fullname into shortcode.

I try with:

```
$myhope = bp_core_get_user_displayname(bp_user_fullname() );
echo do_shortcode( '[wcv_products vendor="'.$myhope.'"]' );
```

But without success. The page is blank.  I wrong the sintax?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want the display name - it may not be unique.

Try using the log-in name instead.

The user name for the displayed profile:

```
$myhope = bp_get_displayed_user_username();
```

The user name for the current user:

```
 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 $myhope = $current_user->user_login;
```

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please accept it: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers